# MySQL filter on the same colum as is ordered by

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

**Desired output:**

I'd like to get 2 rows dated `2019-11-23 17:25:00` and earlier in ascending order, so I wouldn't have to sort them on the application layer.

```
|2019-11-23 17:24:00|
|2019-11-23 17:25:00|
```

---

**My table:** *(I left out unnecessary data for purposes of this question.)*

```
+===================+
|starttime          |
+===================+
|2019-11-23 17:22:00|
|2019-11-23 17:23:00|
|2019-11-23 17:24:00|
|2019-11-23 17:25:00|
|2019-11-23 17:26:00|
|2019-11-23 17:27:00|
+===================+
```

---

**What I've tried so far:**

1) This query returns the first 2 items (incorrect):

```
SELECT `starttime`
FROM `table`
WHERE `starttime` <= "2019-11-23 17:25:00"
ORDER BY `starttime` ASC
LIMIT 2
```

returned data:

```
|2019-11-23 17:22:00|
|2019-11-23 17:23:00|
```

2) This query returns the correct 2 items but in opposite order:

```
SELECT `starttime`
FROM `table`
WHERE `starttime` <= "2019-11-23 17:25:00"
ORDER BY `starttime` DESC
LIMIT 2
```

returned data

```
|2019-11-23 17:25:00|
|2019-11-23 17:24:00|
```

Comment: (sorting on the application layer is normally a fairly trivial activity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2nd query is correct and all you have to do is nest it inside another where you will reorder the 2 rows:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
  SELECT `starttime`
  FROM `table`
  WHERE `starttime` <= "2019-11-23 17:25:00"
  ORDER BY `starttime` DESC
  LIMIT 2
) t
ORDER BY t.`starttime`
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e9Wz9bqYu3xx2VkQvwuaGx/0).